# Where have the cross and dot products gone in DirectX10?

Tags: directx

In directX9 there were functions to deal with D3DXVECTOR3's in order to calculate dot and cross products:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205508(v=VS.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205507(v=VS.85).aspx

However these have dissappeared from the D3DXMath library in DX10.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205164(v=vs.85).aspx

I assume they must have gone somewhere? My question is where, and also why? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know in DX10 D3DXMath still exists however for DX11 it was replaced in favour for XNAMath which is compatable for xbox and pc. (which was my first guess for missing functionality)

I did a quick check and my (latest june 2010) sdk using D3DX10Math.h gave me the option for

D3DXVec3Dot() and D3DXVec3Cross()

[D3DXVec3Dot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205508%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
[D3DXVec3Cross](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205507%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Is it just a case that documentation page not linking them? (my links are for dx9 but in visual studio intellisense showed them for d3dx10Math)